# Missing the action during a converse

Tags: wit.ai

I could use some help understanding the converse option for wit.ai
I've build a simple story with some steps in it.
The dialog should go as follow:

- 1) User: I want to create a new user
- -> intent : newUser
- Bot: Ok, let do this! I need a ...
- 2) User: His name is [someName]
- -> gender: male
- -> name: [name]
- trigger function: saveUser()
- 3) saveUser return: name && missingEmail
- Bot: could you give me the email for [name]
- 4) user: his email is [email]
- bookmark to saveUser()
- saveUser return email && sentMail.. etc etc

During training the my bot understand everything.
But during testing with postman I get a "type":"stop" @ step 2.
After playing around with the action tab I've got to step 3) of even 4) with a action in the responds, but then I get a "stop" in the next step. It doesnt make any sence to me. I've found some related questions from other users with the same question, but no answer..

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? I've could really use some help on this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I've run into a similar issue, and it makes zero sense. It happens to me every time I do a push to my heroku server, then I have to do a restart to fix it. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope, a lot of people are having the same issue. Currently I'm using a combination of Watson conversation and wit.ai message API to skip the whole wit.ai story mode

Comment: I'm just using story mode to drive to my initial action then handling everything. I figured out my error, or at least how to bypass it. It was the sessionID. I reset it more often now and don't use the actual userID.